# Update google map from postcode on page load

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-geocoder

I'm trying to generate a map on page load from a postcode value.

To do this I'm geocoding the dynamic postcode that is given and I have got it to give me a longitude and latitude from that dynamic postcode.

The postcode is sent from a form on a previous page and is stored in the url like so:

```
url.com?postcode=XXXXXX
```

The problem now is how do I join up the longitude and latitude values to pass through into the following:

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(longitude, latitude)
```

This is the JS I have at the moment:

```
var postcodeValue = $('#map').attr('data-postcode');
  function latLong(location, callback) {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var address = location;
  var longitude;
  var latitude;
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
      longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
      callback(latitude, longitude);
    }
  });
}

latLong(postcodeValue, function(lat, lon) {
  console.log(lat);
  console.log(lon);
});

var options = {
  mapTypeControlOptions: {
    mapTypeIds: [ 'Styled']
  },
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(latLong),
  zoom: 12,
  mapTypeId: 'Styled',
  disableDefaultUI: true,
  draggable: false,
  disableDoubleClickZoom: true
};

var div = document.getElementById('map');
var map = new google.maps.Map(div, options);
var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles);

map.mapTypes.set('Styled', styledMapType);
```

Anyone able to help with this please?

Comment: You want to read the postcode (or address to be geocoded) from the query string, pass it to the geocoder and use the returned location to initialize your map?

Comment: I don't see any code in your question to read the query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do, is read the hash.  Example: mywebsite.com#9000 .  Any thing to the right of the hash is ideal to be used as variables for javascript.

I added some links to 3 Belgian cities.  href="?1#1000" , href="?2#8000".  Notice: the "?1" and "?2" are just added to make sure the URL is different (left of the #), otherwise the web browser won't change the page.

I disabled a few of your lines of code regarding the map style.  Feel free to add the back.

Look at line 9 to change the country.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Update google map from postcode on page load</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
  <script>
  function initialize() {
    // read the hash in the url
    var postcodeValue = window.location.hash.substring(1) || 1000 ;// example:  mywebsite.com?p=maps#1000  ;  1000 is default, if no postal code is in the url
    postcodeValue += ', BE';  // probably best to add a country

    var div = document.getElementById('map');
    var map;

    latLong(postcodeValue, function(lat, lon) {
      var options = {
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
          // mapTypeIds: [ 'Styled']
        },
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
        zoom: 12,
        // mapTypeId: 'Styled',
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        draggable: false,
        disableDoubleClickZoom: true
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(div, options);
    });

    // var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles);
    // map.mapTypes.set('Styled', styledMapType);

    function latLong(location, callback) {
      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      var address = location;
      var longitude;
      var latitude;
      geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
      }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
          longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
          callback(latitude, longitude);
        }
      });
    }
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
  <style>
    #map {
      height: 400px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="?1#1000">Brussels</a>
  <a href="?2#8000">Bruges</a>
  <a href="?3#9000">Ghent</a>
  <div id="map">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. read the "postcode" parameter from the query string
2. pass that to the geocoder
3. use that to set the center/zoom of the map
   (not that the code snippet below sets a default address of New York, NY that will remain if the geocode of the postcode fails.

```js
var map = null;

function initialize() {
  var options = {
    /* mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: ['Styled']
    }, */
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    zoom: 4,
    // mapTypeId: 'Styled',
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    draggable: false,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true
  };

  var div = document.getElementById('map');
  map = new google.maps.Map(div, options);
  // var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles);

  // map.mapTypes.set('Styled', styledMapType);

  // default location
  codeAddress("New York, NY");
  
  // If there are any parameters at eh end of the URL, they will be in  location.search
  // looking something like  "?marker=3"

  // skip the first character, we are not interested in the "?"
  var query = location.search.substring(1);

  // split the rest at each "&" character to give a list of  "argname=value"  pairs
  var pairs = query.split("&");
  for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
    // break each pair at the first "=" to obtain the argname and value
    var pos = pairs[i].indexOf("=");
    var argname = pairs[i].substring(0, pos).toLowerCase();
    switch (argname) {
      case "postcode":
        var value = pairs[i].substring(pos + 1);
        codeAddress(value);
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',initialize);

function codeAddress(location) {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': location
  }, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[0].geometry.viewport) 
        map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
      else if (results[0].geometry.bounds)
        map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.bounds);
      else map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```